# Problems with Miktex and Texlipse

Tags: errors, miktex, miktex2.9, texlipse, compilation-error

I'm trying to work with Eclipse (Texlipse) and MikTex but I have problems to make a project. Console send me the next information:

```
running: C:\miktex29\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials document.tex     
pdflatex.exe> log4cxx: setFile(C:\Users\juan joslog4cxx: IO Exception : status code = 720003
pdflatex.exe> log4cxx: No output stream or file set for the appender named [RollingLogFile].
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> Sorry, but C:\miktex29\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe>   C:/Users/juan josâ/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
pdflatex.exe> 
pdflatex.exe> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

I've reinstalled it a lot time and I've changed the directory but it still send me the same.

Searching by internet I've found that "accent" in path directory maybe give me problems, so I've change the folder directory.

```
pdflatex.exe> log4cxx: setFile(C:\Users\juan joslog4cxx: IO Exception : status code = 720003
```

When I watch the console I notice pdflatex.exe try to go to other directory and that directory has a "accent" in his name.

The directory is C:\Users\juan jos**é**... I'm try to understand if there are some command or option to give to pdflatex and it can understand that path has an "accent" but I couldn't to make some like it. I think that could be my trouble but maybe not.

Adding information, I've found in setup.log:

```
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mpmcli).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

Maybe my troubles are for that.
Help please

Comment: A similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/203)

Comment: @ChristianSchenk I've read that post but I'm still continue with same problem.
I've downloaded a current MikTex but I even have problem.

Comment: I've added info

Comment: I am quite sure that this is a MiKTeX bug. I have cloned your question and created a ticket here:
[https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/210](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/210)

Comment: @ChristianSchenk from GitHub it looks like this has been resolved. I don't have Windows to test this, maybe you can add an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by an update of MiKTeX (see close bug report mentioned in comments)